# Testing hooks that have useEffect with react-hooks-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing

```
export async function useCustomHook(data) {
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log('useEffect called');

    async function callRemote() {
      const isAuthenticated = await someApi();
      data.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }
  }, [data]);

  callRemote();
}
```

```
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks/server";
import { useCustomHook } from '../useCustomHook';

test('it should set data obj', () => {
  const dataMock = {};
  renderHook(() => 
    useCustomHook(dataMock);
  );

  expect(data.isAuthenticated).toBe(true);
})
```

The `useEffect` never gets called.
The line `console.log('useEffect called');` isn't called.

Why isn't the useEffect hook every called in the test?

Comment: Any error message on this please?

Comment: There isn't an error message. The test just fails because useEffect is never called. Question is WHY the useEffect is NOT called.

Comment: callRemote is async function i guess you need to await. See this documentation: https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async

Comment: I think it should throw `ReferenceError` since `data` is not defined in your second code block.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using the wrong `renderHook`. I updated the import to be

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
```

instead of from `@testing-library/react-hooks/server`.

There are other issues with the test, but now `useEffect` will run.

Also need to update the test env in jest to `jsdom`.

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};
```